# Variable "widget_type" does not exist in SonataAdminBundle:Form:filter_admin_fields.html.twig

Tags: symfony, blogs, sonata-admin

I have created sonata blog bundle from this [link](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/tutorial/creating_your_first_admin_class/defining_entities.html)

**My appKarnel**

```
new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle(),
new Acme\MainBundle\AcmeMainBundle(),
new Acme\SliderBundle\AcmeSliderBundle(),
new Acme\ProjectBundle\AcmeProjectBundle(),
new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
new Sonata\jQueryBundle\SonatajQueryBundle(),
new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),
new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),
new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle(),
```

But when I want to render post lists showing error:

> Variable "widget_type" does not exist in
>   SonataAdminBundle:Form:filter_admin_fields.html.twig in line 36

Answer (score 0):

there is a pull request that makes reference to your question https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/2067